# Generalization of Mills' theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Mills' theorem states that there exists a positive real number $A$ such that the floor of the double exponential function $A^{3^n}$ are primes for all positive integers $n$. The value of $A$ is approximately $1.306$...., and primes generated by this constant A is $2,11,1361,....$, these are called as Mills' primes.

Now I want make some kind of generalization of this Mill's theorem: *There exist 2 positive real numbers $B$ and $C$, such that the floor of the double exponential function $B^{C^n}$ are primes for all positive integers $n$*. The values of $B$ and $C$ are chosen to be **as smallest as possible**, so it can generates the sequence of distinct increasing primes that are **smallest as possible**. I made an experiment and I have a problem of determining the values of $B$ and $C$, because it grows very fast. Does anyone able to determine the value of $B$ and $C$? What is the values of $B$ and $C$ might be?

Comment: What does "smallest as possible" mean in the two bolded expressions?

Comment: You might find [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Caldwell/caldwell78.pdf) paper of interest.

Comment: @senpuretsuzan you should review the original Mills paper to understand the values that can be used for $B$ and $C$. I wrote a similar question to yours here some weeks ago. I was able to reduce the growth of the sequence of primes with a little trick based on Mills results.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807823/are-my-calculations-of-a-new-constant-similar-to-mills-constant-based-on-lflo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find such positive real numbers $B$ and $C$, you first need to understand Mills' proof of his original prime-representing formula. It's only one page, you can read it freely online here:

[PDF link to Mills' paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-06/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2.pdf)